# HTML-Formular: Display given select-options on user selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, twitter-bootstrap-3

we are using a not-so-cool shop service where a product with different models ends up in a huge select list form. Like 21 options if we say 7 different cheese types, 3 different bun types. Their way to validate the product is by checking a single id (12345) for each bun with cheese.

**Example**

```
<form action="https://www.not-so-cool.com/shop/checkout/" method="get" class="form-inline" target="_blank">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="54321">
    <input type="hidden" name="pid" value="543211">
    <select name="md" class="form-control">
        <option>Choose</option>
        <option value="12345"> A 3.50 $</option>
        <option value="12346"> A 2.00 $</option>
        <option value="12347"> A 3.00 $</option>
        <option value="12348"> A 1.00 $</option>
        <option value="12349"> A 2.50 $</option>
        <option value="12350"> A 1.50 $</option>
        <option value="12351"> A 4.50 $</option>
        <option value="12345"> B 3.50 $</option>
        <option value="12346"> B 2.00 $</option>
        <option value="12347"> B 3.00 $</option>
        <option value="12348"> B 1.00 $</option>
        <option value="12349"> B 2.50 $</option>
        <option value="12350"> B 1.50 $</option>
        <option value="12351"> B 4.50 $</option>
        <option value="12345"> B 3.50 $</option>
        <option value="12346"> C 2.00 $</option>
        <option value="12347"> C 3.00 $</option>
        <option value="12348"> C 1.00 $</option>
        <option value="12349"> C 2.50 $</option>
        <option value="12350"> C 1.50 $</option>
        <option value="12351"> C 4.50 $</option>
        <option value="12351"> C 4.50 $</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="buy!" class="btn btn-success btn-lg">
</form>
```

Beautiful right?
**Do you guys know a way how give the user a pre-selection for pun-type and only display the remaining 7 cheese-types?**
Or only display a hard coded form where we already defined the 7 cheese-types form related to a pun-type?

Comment: Two drop downs... one for bun type, one for cheese type...

Comment: How does the cheese type dropdown knows which bun was chosen to be eaten? :-)

Comment: Does it need to? So only some buns can have certain cheese types?... then you need javascript to detect `onchange` of bun drop down and then set the cheese list (which is something you should try to solve on your own)

Comment: Yeah because the shop service only want to know the unique combination/value id. Can't just send bun and cheese. I'll try to find a onchange way. Since today I only was a html/css guy!

Comment: [Have a look at this](https://jsfiddle.net/f58Ljb65/) might give you some ideas

Comment: That helped! It is jQuery right? So me and future beginners have to read more in their docs?

Comment: Yes, I used JQuery as you tagged it. Though you can do it all without JQuery, it's just easier with it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Watch musefans comment (jsfiddle).
"Genereate" all `<options>` with jQuery append() based on another option-form.